# Multi vlan internet access via Watchguard

Tags: networking, firewall, routing, switch, vlan

i'm pretty new to network and routing so i would appreciate some tips on this.

I have a firewall(watchguard x1250e), connecting to a switch(Nortel Baystack 5510) with multiple vlans for internet access.

Interface 0(External) of the FW being the public internet gateway. Public IP address

Interface 1(Optional) of the FW being the internal network gateway. 192.168.5.1/24

Interface 1  of the FW will be connected to a switch with vlan IP interface 192.168.5.254/24

**vlan interface on the switch**

vlan 2(pvid=2) - 192.168.2.254/24, Ports 1-12 = untagged

vlan 3(pvid=3) - 192.168.3.254/24, Ports 13-18 = untagged

vlan 4(pvid=4) - 192.168.4.254/24, Ports 19-20 = untagged

vlan 5(no pvid) - 192.168.5.254/24, Ports 21-22 = tagged (internet vlan)

IP routing is enabled on switch, so there is inter-vlan routing.

**Configurations on the FW**

NAT settings on the watchguard is being set as dynamic NAT which translates Interface 1 packets to the public IP address of Interface 0

Static Routes on the watchguard is being set as

192.168.2.0/24 -> 192.168.5.1

192.168.3.0/24 -> 192.168.5.1

192.168.4.0/24 -> 192.168.5.1

Of course, PC connected to vlan 5 is able to access internet with no issues.

IP address of PC: 192.168.5.20/24, GW: 192.168.5.254, DNS: 8.8.8.8

However, my PC connected to other vlans are not able to access internet.
I'm not sure what settings have i missed out/or have configured wrongly.

Please help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you adding static routes on the Watchguard pointing the other networks to the *Watchguard's* IP address? Shouldn't they go to the switch's IP address instead, e.g. `192.168.2.0/24 -> 192.168.5.254`?